# <Error> <main.c> in simple program

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ABC(int &n) // Error=> expected ')'
{
     printf("n=");
     scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

Help me, please! Thank you :)

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: C doesn't have C++-style references... if you're doing pass-by-reference, use pointers.

Comment: You should be more specific , in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to get the arguments as address using the ampersand(&). So you can use the 
pointer to get the address of one variable.

```
int ABC(int *n)
{
   scanf("%d",n);
}
```

While passing to that function, you have to pass the address of the variable.

```
int a;
ABC(&a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [Question 4.11](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html) of C-FAQ

> **Q**: Does C even have ``pass by reference''?
>
> **A**: Not really.
>
> Strictly speaking, C always uses pass by value. You can simulate pass
>   by reference yourself, by defining functions which accept pointers and
>   then using the & operator when calling, and the compiler will
>   essentially simulate it for you when you pass an array to a function
>   (by passing a pointer instead, see question 6.4 et al.).
>
> Another way of looking at it is that if an parameter has type, say,
>   int * then an integer is being passed by reference and a pointer to an
>   integer is being passed by value.
>
> Fundamentally, C has nothing truly equivalent to formal pass by
>   reference or C++ reference parameters. (On the other hand,
>   function-like preprocessor macros can provide a form of ``pass by
>   name''.)
>
> See also questions 4.8, 7.9, 12.27, and 20.1.

To simulate a pass by reference:

```
int ABC(int *n) 
{
     printf("n=");
     scanf("%d", n);
     printf("%d\n", *n);
     return 0;
}
```

Call it using `&`:

```
int x;
ABC(&x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is the `address of` operator, it can't be passed as argument to a function.

If you want to fix your code, you need to pass the argument `n` without `&`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ABC(int n) 
{
     printf("n=");
     scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code i tried in c++ it worked just return a value and see hope this may give you an idea

```
int ABC(int &n) 
{
     printf("n=")
     scanf_s("%d",&n);
     return n;
}
```

Comment: Question is tagged `C` and `xcode`, and `scanf_s` is specific to Microsoft compilers.